# If And statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I'm trying to have a statement 'if scroll and has a class, do an action.

however I don't manage to have it working . . .

I've tried below code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop() > 1 && $(".menu-toggle").hasClass(".toggle-on")) {   
    // $('.toggle-on')
    $( 'body' ).removeClass( 'overlay-open' );
    $( '.menu-toggle' ).removeClass( 'toggle-on hide' );
    $( '.menu-toggle' ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
    $( '.overlay--menu' ).removeClass( 'show' ).resize();
    $( '.search-toggle' ).removeClass( 'hide' );
    $( '.chapter-toggle' ).removeClass( 'hide' );
    $('.overlay--menu').addClass('hidemenu');
  }
});
```

any help will be really amazing !!

Thanks for your time !

Comment: your `)` is in the wrong place. it has to follow the entire condition, not just the first half of it.

Comment: oups, that was my mistake, i have edit with what I am using

Comment: .hasClass expects a classname, not a selector.

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: nothing happen.

If i remove the && section it works. but I need the function to work only  for when there is the toggle-on class . . .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You almost had it!
You have your right parenthesis out of place.

Try changing the conditional from,
`if($(this).scrollTop() > 1) && $(".menu-toggle").hasClass("toggle-on") {`
to
`if($(this).scrollTop() > 1 && $(".menu-toggle").hasClass("toggle-on")){`

The basic idea is that you'd have both conditionals within the parenthesis, separated by `&&`, such as
`if (this && that)`.